# How to enable message button Facebook public profile view?

Tags: facebook

When I view my own Facebook profile as seen by public, I noticed Message button is disabled as shown in picture below. This means public who are not my friends will not be able to message me or send me message request.

[image: facebook]

My setting page is:

[image: facebook2]

Other forums suggest there is settings page under Privacy and there is a link like "Who can send you Facebook messages?: (drop drown selection button)" But there is no such link.

I want to enable Message button on my public profile. How can I do that?

Screenshot showing privacy settings:

[image: privacy settings]

Comment: Second screenshot is General settings, click on privacy and show us what setting you are seeing there and what option you have selected.

Comment: privacy settings screenshot is added to question.